# Mysql database restoration from folder backup

Tags: server, permissions, 20.04, mysql, backup

I need to restore from folder backup my mysql databases.
I have a complete `/var/lib/mysql` folder backed up with all the files.
I have a fresh install of mysql. I copied back from the backup the database folders and all of the `ibdata` and `ib_logfile` files. I set up the permissions for the new files with `chown -R mysql:mysql`. The server starts without problems but cant "see" the databases copied from backup if I list the databases from mysql prompt.
Any idea how to get mysql see the backup databases?

Comment: The original server went down, and i have just the /var/lib/mysql folder backup...

Comment: Ok! Answer is from memory so be careful :)

Answer (score 1):

> I copied back from the backup the databse folders and all of the ibdata and ib_logfile files.

With `cp`? If so I was told to use rsync for this.

Stop mysql with `sudo service stop mysql`

From an old version of /var/lib/mysql/

```
sudo rsync -av /{backup_dir}/ /var/lib/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql
```

Start mysql with `sudo service start mysql`

Check for errors before proceeding (onscreen and `/var/log/mysql`)

And set your system up to create automatic dumps with mysqldump and have those backups stored on another partition or even another system.

Comment: Thats not working: 2020-07-19T12:36:13.200089Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013171] [InnoDB] Cannot boot server version 80020 on data directory built by version 80021. Downgrade is not supported
mysqld: Can't open file: 'mysql.ibd' (errno: 0 - )
2020-07-19T12:36:18.212873Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-07-19T12:36:18.213249Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-07-19T12:36:18.213511Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Comment: You need to use the SAME MYSQL. Not an older or newer version.